# Equality operator issue (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error

> no match for 'operator==' in 'MyNestedClassPointer->MyClass::MyNestedClass::NestedVar == s'

Where s is a reference to a string, and NestedVar is a pointer to a string.
The offending line of code is an if statement comparing the two to see if they're identical.

```
if(thePointer->theVar == s)
```

I have no overloaded operators, but I don't think I should have a need for them, seeing as these are just string pointers we're dealing with.
Now correct me if I'm wrong, since I'm more than a little rusty, but can't I do this?

Comment: if NestedVar is a pointer, it needs to be dereferenced (`*` operator) before doing the comparison, otherwise you're comparing a pointer with an string, when you want to compare the pointed to string with a string.

Comment: You might also like to provide the declarations for the 2 variables in your question too.

Comment: What's the type of `s` ? `char *` or `std::string`

Comment: Basically I'm trying to compare a pointer to a pointer, to s, which is a function parameter of type string&. It's been a long time, so forgive my memory, but I thought the '->' operator dereferenced what it pointed to?

Comment: @user2778542

You are right, the `->` operator dereferences, however you mentioned that it is a pointer to a pointer, therefore you need to dereference twice. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the comments has mentioned, the correct syntax to compare a `pointer to string object` and a `string object` is by dereferencing the pointer.

Therefore in your code, it should be:

```
if( *thePointer->theVar == s )
```

Comment: Hopefully this IS actually the problem. There's not quite enough info in the question to be sure. :)

Comment: Thank you both, I just had to remember how to dereference in that style, I hardly ever had to use it in the past so I guess it just slipped out of memory.